# Is there a way to transcode example blocks differently from src results?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I'd like to have

```
#+results:
: Hello world
```

export as

```
\begin{results}
Hello world
\end{results}
```

while I want example blocks to export as...

```
\begin{verbatim}
This is an example
\end{verbatim}
```

How can I create a custom transcoder to look for the `#+results:` tag & export as desired?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:wrap results` header](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html) in the source block<sup>1</sup>. That will produce a `#+BEGIN_results ... #+END_results` block on evaluation:

```org
#+begin_src shell :wrap results :exports results
echo "Hello world"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_results
Hello world
#+end_results

#+begin_example
This is an example
#+end_example
```

Instead of adding the header explicitly to the code block, you can set default header-args for your document via [a global property](https://orgmode.org/guide/Properties.html) by adding the line:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :wrap results
```

somewhere in your document  (usually at the top), and subsequently pressing `C-c C-c` with your cursor on that line to refresh (or close and re-open the document), or through a property drawer (either global at the top of the file or local within a section):

```org
:PROPERTIES:
:header_args: :wrap results
:END:
```

See [Using header args](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html) in the manual.

The LaTeX exporter will transcode that to a `\begin{results}... \end{results}` environment:

```tex
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{results}
Hello world
\end{results}

\begin{verbatim}
This is an example
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

The definition of a `results` environment is your responsibility however: LaTeX doesn't have anything built-in defining that environment, so you'll have to define it in your own package.

---

[1] Actually an empty `:wrap` will do: `results` is the default environment in that case.